# Datetime is being printed with brackets , single quotes and comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am making a "Date Temperature" for a live Line chart for my raspberry pi3 project.

I have done the following code:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
dateformat = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
testtemperature = 10
data = (dateformat,testtemperature)
data = str(data)
file= open("test.txt","a")
file.write(data)
file.close()
print (data)
```

but its printing or outputting:

```
('15-05-2017', 10)
```

instead of:

"15-05-2017 10"
How can i remove the Brackets,single quotes and the comma ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string formatting when you define data.

```
data = "{} {}".format(dateformat,testtemperature)
```

In context, it will be:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
dateformat = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
testtemperature = 10
data = "{} {}".format(dateformat,testtemperature)
file = open("test.txt","a")
file.write(data)
file.close()
print (data) # prints "15-05-2017 10"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
print(*data)
```

which gives:

```
15-05-2017 10
```

The `*` indicates that you wish to "unpack" the tuple `data` and print each of them separately.